# Syntax error near "COUNT (*)"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'd like to do an interactive stored procedure 
I mean, after execution the user should type a word

I wrote this but it doesn't work..

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ric_forn$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  ric_forn (IN nome_forn VARCHAR(100) , OUT msg VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
DECLARE num_rec INT;

IF (nome_forn = '') THEN 
    SET msg = "Attenzione il nome inserito non è valido !";
END IF;

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO num_rec FROM Fornitori WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;

IF num_rec = 0 THEN
    SET msg = "Nessun record trovato !";

ELSE

SELECT Id_Fornitore,Des_Fornitore,Ind_Fornitore WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;
    SET msg = "Records trovati:";

END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*) INTO num_rec FROM Fornitori WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;

Comment: Well, does `SELECT COUNT (*) INTO num_rec FROM Fornitori WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;` work from the CLI?

Comment: I'm a beginner ..what do you mean by CLI?...Thanks

Comment: ok sorry you mean from the shell..even if I comment out that line things don't go smoothly anyway..

Comment: Yes, try it on it's own (with the appropriate variables declared). CLI = Command Line Interface (or "from the shell") -- it won't work (and will have the same error) but will lead to easily experimenting with the syntax "near COUNT (*)".

Comment: Have you tried `SET num_rec = SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Fornitori WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;` instead

Comment: I tried that but to no avail..thanks

Answer (score 14):

The space between `COUNT` and `(*)` is significant.  You should put them together, don't leave a space.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ...
```

Exception is if you `SET SQL_MODE='IGNORE_SPACE'`.  Read [Function Name Parsing and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html) for more details.

---

Your other error is that you forgot the `FROM` clause in one of your queries:

```
SELECT Id_Fornitore,Des_Fornitore,Ind_Fornitore WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;
```

Should be:

```
SELECT Id_Fornitore,Des_Fornitore,Ind_Fornitore FROM Fornitori
WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;
```

Comment: I removed the space as you said,,now I get a different error which points to --> WHERE Des_Fornitore = nome_forn;
    SET msg = "Records trovati:";
thanks